# not able to install gcc on ubuntu 18.04.01

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu-18.04

I have just installed `Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS` and I am trying to use the `make` command to compile my `Makefile` which is located in the same `directory` as my `simple.c` file. After running `make` I get the error that I don't have `gcc` installed. When I try to install it, I get the errors below. The problem is that I can't install gcc and I don't know why? I will also put the `Makefile` code also.

`Error Output`

`gn:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 4.15.0-43.46
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 4.15.0-43.46
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_4.15.0-43.46_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?`

`MakeFile`

`obj-m += simple.o
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean`

Comment: Did you run `apt-get update`?

Comment: Yes I did it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `sudo apt-get update` does not work for you, you should maybe try `sudo apt-get clean` to clean the cache and then execute `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: @moegizzle and you tried: sudo apt-get update --fix-missing

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be your problem, but I had the same issue when first
installing my copy of Ubuntu 18.04.01. I did not yet have the drivers of
my wifi-dongle installed, and, as such, I couldn't reach any site
(including the sites of Ubuntu working with package updates).

So, it may be an internet-related issue. I read in the comments that
you *could* execute `apt-get update`. Maybe there is a different
connection issue at work? I would check those settings.

Comment: I thought it was network related but I am connected to the internet and can access websites.

Answer (score 0):

I flashed a new ubuntu 18 bionic desktop onto my disk and, installed apache and PHP by "apt-get" then did about 300MB of "updates", including "security updates" (which include localization files ?????) and to my shock and horror, ubuntu doesnt have a c compiler but insists on havig c libraries anyway to make it difficult to install a c compiler.

The easy option of tcc which is Tiny C Compiler but I think the kernel is complied using gnu and almost every is using gnu so you probably want that specific compiler. So heres what I did, maybe Im being too "-v" and someone can edit this to the bare essentials but straight from the box this is where Im at and this is what I did next...

1.

```
sudo apt install synaptic
```

then

2. Did a search (name and description) for "libc6-dev"
3. Marked it for installation.
4. Hit the apply button and a window shows up saying its going to be installed and tells me there will be extra packages installed and some packages downgraded.

5 I hit the okay button and it starts committing the changes finally saying "Changes applied".

6 Switched off synaptic and went to console but gcc still wasnt installing.

7 I went back to synaptic and tried to footer around a bit but nope so I went to the console again and said

```
sudo apt install aptitude
```

then

```
sudo aptitude install gcc
```

and it suggested I accept the solution of installing nothing at all so I went "no" and it gave me an alternative which involved downgrading and adding extra packages and I went "yes" and the hamster wheel turned for a while and eventually I got my prompt back and went

```
gcc
```

and it said:

gcc:"fatal error: no input files"
compilation terminated.

and I went "WEHEY! IT WORKS!" (not recognising the irony)

Now lets see what Ive broken in the process of installing gcc...